# Sscanf ожидает тип double, хотя должен быть float

Tags: c, типы-данных, ввод

Для всех аргументов функции sscanf (1-3) высвечивается

> warning C4477: "sscanf": в строке форматирования "%f" требуется аргумент типа "float *", но вариативный аргумент "1" имеет тип "double"

Но почему ожидается тип double, и как исправить данную проблему?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


void get_numbers(const char* msg, float nums[3]) {
    char answer[256];

    printf("%s", msg);
    fgets(answer, sizeof(answer), stdin);

    while (sscanf(answer, "%f %f %f", nums[0], nums[1], nums[2]) != 3) {
        printf("Incorrect input. Try again: ");
        fgets(answer, sizeof(answer), stdin);
    }
}


int main(void) {
    const char* msg = "Enter three numbers: ";
    float nums[3];
    float summ;

    get_numbers(msg, nums);

    summ = nums[0] + nums[1] + nums[2];

    printf("Square root of the sum of numbers = %f", sqrt(summ));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"Но почему ожидается тип double"* - ¿Вот с чего вы решили, что там ожидается double, когда в ошибке черным по белому написано `требуется аргумент типа "float *"`?

Comment: Опечатался. Тут та же ситуация, как и с решением этого вопроса - сегодня какой-то совсем невнимательный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уже неоднократно писалось, что `*scanf` функции требуют указателей, а не просто значений. Добавление нескольких амперсандов решает Вашу проблему

```
while (sscanf(answer, "%f %f %f", &nums[0], &nums[1], &nums[2]) != 3)
```

Comment: У меня просто ступор мозговины, либо же я слепой. Но спасибо, минут 40 пытался решить эту проблему, не замечая очевидную вещь

Comment: бывает. что поделать